# Question about using “a” in sentence

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles, parallelism

I don’t even know how to accurately ask this question, but I need to know which of the following is correct:

> Tom Smith is an Arizona native and partner at the Law Offices of Smith & Smith.

Or

> Tom Smith is an Arizona native and **a** partner at the Law Offices of Smith & Smith.

Basically the question is can the “an” in the first part of the sentence be correctly applied to the word “partner” (which normally would require an “a”).

Comment: You will need to do some explaining here. By your reasoning, the "an" can't apply to "native", either. Yet it does and you are okay with that. So what is so special about "partner" as opposed to "native" that "an" can apply to one but not the other? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write it like this:

a native of Arizona and partner at ABC.

For me, there is no need for a second a and by saying of Arizona, the an/a thing goes away.

This seems to be a general rule in writing.

> Hence we see that when two or more connected nouns refer to the same
>   person or thing, the Article is ordinarily used before the first only;
>   but when two or more connected nouns refer to different persons or
>   things, the article is used before each. Also examine the following
>   sentences: John was a great orator and statesman.

[repetition of article](http://how2learnskills.blogspot.com/2012/04/repetition-of-article.html)

Comment: But: *An officer and **a** gentleman.*